# Why is OmniSharp looking for runtime version 1.0.0-beta3 instead of our specified version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

We're working on our first ASP.NET 5 project with Visual Studio Code. We've installed DNVM and DNX. We've also checked out the NewMVC6Project from the ASP.NET's GitHub account. Further, we've configured our web server within project.json as follows.

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {        
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener" : "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "commands": {
      "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001"  
    },
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

Also, when we run `dnvm list` we receive this output.

```
Active Version     Runtime Architecture Location                       Alias
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------                       -----
  *    1.0.0-beta4 clr     x86          C:\Users\BigFont\.dnx\runtimes default
```

Still, we receive this error when opening the project's folder in Visual Studio Code.

```
> The specified runtime path '1.0.0-beta3' does not exist. Searched locations %USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3
```

Why is it looking for 1.0.0-beta3 instead of 1.0.0-beta4? How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in our global.json file. The directory structure goes like this:

```
NewMVC6Project
    src             
        NewMVC6Project
            project.json
            other-stuff-omitted
    global.json     
    NewMvc6Project.sln
```

Even though the project.json was appropriately configured, the global.json need to change from this:

```
{
    "sources": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta3"
    }
}
```

... to this:

```
{
    "sources": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had an issue where OmniSharp was erroring because it couldn't find a runtime named 'default'.  I had removed that alias and created my own (mono and coreclr).  I created a global.json file and stuck in the version as "coreclr" and now I don't get the OmniSharp error any more and more importantly - I'm getting some Intellisense.